# Move oracle 19c installation to a lvm partition

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Im trying to install Oracle 19c on Centos 8 using rpm. It keeps installing in /opt where dont have enough space. I have created a separate partition (LVM) where I want to put oracle but there is no way to specify the directory of installation.
I tried moving the directory and when trying to install /etc/init.d/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-firstboot configure its complaining about lots of stuff. I tried to change the files to point to the current dir but still failing.
Anyone can help please?

Comment: Not sure if you can do that when using install from rpm. You can install from a gold-image, where you unzip it to wherever you want and then runInstaller.

Comment: Thanks mate. I guess installing from good image would be a pain because of dependencies?

Comment: for dependencies, you have a "preinstall" rpm that does that. Follow the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/automatically-configuring-oracle-linux-with-oracle-preinstallation-rpm.html#GUID-22846194-58EF-4552-AAC3-6F6D0A1DF794) and it will be ok.

Comment: Yep I have done that..had to do before installing the rpm..thanks though..

Comment: Can you use a response file to install on another directory?

Comment: Why bother, unzip it where you want to and install. Maybe doable, not sure.